# How to do a 2 finger tap in Appium using W3C actions?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

There are many tutorials on doing a 1 finger tap, swipe, double tap, but none that I can find to do a 2 finger tap.

I think w3c Actions may be a Selenium construct, and 2 finger taps aren't something you do in a desktop browser... but I'm surprised I can't find helpful info online.

Or maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree?  All I know is that TouchActions are deprecated and we seem to be moving (back) to w3c.

A 1 finger tap may look something like this:

```
PointerInput finger01 = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger01");
PointerInput.PointerEventProperties pep = new PointerInput.PointerEventProperties();
java.time.Duration duration0 = java.time.Duration.ofMillis(0);
java.time.Duration duration100 = java.time.Duration.ofMillis(100);
PointerInput.Origin vp = PointerInput.Origin.viewport();

Sequence tapSeq = new Sequence(finger01, 1);
tapSeq.addAction(finger01.createPointerMove(duration0, vp, 300, 400));
tapSeq.addAction(finger01.createPointerDown(0, pep));
tapSeq.addAction(finger01.createPointerMove(duration100, vp, 300, 400));
tapSeq.addAction(finger01.createPointerUp(0, pep));
```

But for a 2 finger tap, I imagine I'd need to add `finger01` and `finger02` (not shown here) to the `Sequence`

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours, here's what I came up with:

```
int x1 = 100;
int y1 = 200;
int x2 = 100;
int y2 = 200;
java.time.Duration duration = java.time.Duration.ofMillis(250); 
PointerInput.Origin vp = PointerInput.Origin.viewport();

PointerInput finger01 = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger01");
Sequence tapSeq01 = new Sequence(finger01, 1);
tapSeq01.addAction(finger01.createPointerMove(duration, vp, x1, y1));
tapSeq01.addAction(finger01.createPointerDown(0));  // button = 0 (left mouse button)
tapSeq01.addAction(finger01.createPointerMove(duration, vp, x1, y1));
tapSeq01.addAction(finger01.createPointerUp(0));

PointerInput finger02 = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger02");
Sequence tapSeq02 = new Sequence(finger02, 1);
tapSeq02.addAction(finger02.createPointerMove(duration, vp, x2, y2));
tapSeq02.addAction(finger02.createPointerDown(0));
tapSeq02.addAction(finger02.createPointerMove(duration, vp, x2, y2));
tapSeq02.addAction(finger02.createPointerUp(0));

driver.perform(Arrays.asList(tapSeq01, tapSeq02));
```